# how to properly incorporate early stopping validation in sklearn Pipeline with ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I want to setup a lightGBM model with early stop validation. I also want to follow the best practice of using Pipeline to combine preprocessing and model fitting and prediction. Code below:

```
coltransformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('cat', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output = False), cat_invar),
    ('num', 'passthrough', num_invar)])

lgbPipe = Pipeline([
    ('preprocess', coltransformer),
    ('lgb', LGBMClassifier()])

X_learn, X_val, Y_learn, Y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

lgbPipe.fit(X_learn, Y_learn, lgb__eval_set = (X_val, Y_val))
```

However, I got the following error message when running the code:

```
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
Did not expect the data types in the following fields: Geography, Gender, Surname
```

It appears the validation datasets (X_val, Y_val) were not being transformed in the preprocessing step. How should I properly setup the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I am open to better solutions however this is what I have discovered:

The Pipeline framework does not natively support eval_set(). The validation data set has to be preprocessed as well as the learning data. The Pipeline fit and transform methods does not take into account the data specified in the eval_set() argument. One has to break out the steps of preprocessing and model fitting separately.

See more discussions in [here](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/questions-and-answers/101994#872092)